# Setting the theme for an android app dynamically with setTheme()

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity that extends ActionBarActivity (extended to be able to display the actionbar in my listFragment). I am attempting to set the theme using setTheme() like this within the OnCreate() method of my activity:

```
setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
setContentView(R.layout.holder);
```

However, I get this error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

When in fact the style I am using as an argument for setTheme() already has a parent as a Theme.AppCompat theme:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="background">@color/GhostWhite</item>
</style>
```

Any answers are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Figured out my problem:*

I had been initially taking out the theme attribute in the application tag in the manifest.

Setting an application wide theme in your manifest application tag seems to be required in order for setTheme() to work properly. Then you are able to override that application wide theme with setTheme() on each activity.

Answer (score 0):

Make a object of theme and apply directly by using setTo(theme) like following.

```
Theme theme; 
theme.setTo(other theme which you want to apply);
```